# Workaround for copying style with PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I want to copy the style information from cells to ranges, like Format Painter in Excel.  The documentation says to do something like this:

```
$activeSheet->duplicateStyle($activeSheet->getStyle('A1'), 'D1:D100');
$activeSheet->duplicateStyle($activeSheet->getStyle('B1'), 'E1:E100');
```

There appears to be a bug because both D1:D100 and E1:E100 get the style from cell B1.  If I change the order of the two lines, both ranges get the style from A1.  Similarly,

```
$styleA = $activeSheet->getStyle('A1');
$styleB = $activeSheet->getStyle('B1');
$activeSheet->duplicateStyle($styleA, 'D1:D100');
```

results in D1:D100 getting style info from cell B1.  The last getStyle value is used in all duplicateStyle results.

I'm sure that a future release of PHPExcel will have a fix, I just need to figure out a work-around until then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One workround for you might be to use the style xf Indexes:

```
$xfIndex = $activeSheet->getCell('A1')->getXfIndex();
```

Then to set that value for the xfIndex of all cells in the range

```
for ($col = 'D'; $col != 'E'; ++$col) {
    for ($row = 1; $row <= 100; ++$row) {
        $activeSheet->getCell($col . $row)->setXfIndex($xfIndex);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, apply fix to the duplicateStyle() method in Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php

lines 1479 to 1486 currently read:

```
if ($this->_parent->cellXfExists($pCellStyle)) {
    // there is already this cell Xf in our collection
    $xfIndex = $pCellStyle->getIndex();
} else {
    // we don't have such a cell Xf, need to add
    $workbook->addCellXf($pCellStyle);
    $xfIndex = $pCellStyle->getIndex();
}
```

change to:

```
if ($existingStyle = $this->_parent->getCellXfByHashCode($pCellStyle->getHashCode())) {
    // there is already such cell Xf in our collection
    $xfIndex = $existingStyle->getIndex();
} else {
    // we don't have such a cell Xf, need to add
    $workbook->addCellXf($pCellStyle);
    $xfIndex = $pCellStyle->getIndex();
}
```

Similarly in the applyFromArray() method in Classes/PHPExcel/Style.php

lines 425 to 432 currently read:

```
if ($workbook->cellXfExists($newStyle)) {
    // there is already such cell Xf in our collection
    $newXfIndexes[$oldXfIndex] = $existingStyle->getIndex();
} else {
    // we don't have such a cell Xf, need to add
    $workbook->addCellXf($newStyle);
    $newXfIndexes[$oldXfIndex] = $newStyle->getIndex();
}
```

change to:

```
if ($existingStyle = $workbook->getCellXfByHashCode($newStyle->getHashCode())) {
    // there is already such cell Xf in our collection
    $newXfIndexes[$oldXfIndex] = $existingStyle->getIndex();
} else {
    // we don't have such a cell Xf, need to add
    $workbook->addCellXf($newStyle);
    $newXfIndexes[$oldXfIndex] = $newStyle->getIndex();
}
```

**EDIT #2**

Fix has now been pushed to the develop branch on github. It does give a slight performance hit, depending on the number of styles in use... I'll try and get a faster version tomorrow night

Comment: Thanks Mark - the patches worked perfectly. Insane support for a fantastic product.

Comment: I found the getXfIndex() and setXfIndex() methods extremely useful. It's a pity PHPExcel's doc is so sparse because without this response I would have never guessed what an Xf is.

Comment: @soger - It's just as much fun figuring out what `xf` is from the Microsoft documentation as well

Comment: Actually it was my fault too because I completely forgot about the file PHPExcel developer documentation.doc that is included when you download the library.  Although not complete (for example getXfIndex() and setXfIndex() is not in it) and a big word doc is not my favorite kind of documentation, it's still useful.