# Copy and paste styles from one row to other

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using [PHP Excel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to create an Excel using a template Excel file. The problem is I have a datagrid and which I styled the header and first row in template. Here how it looks like:

[image: template]

The top leftmost coordinate is C49.

If I have 100 rows, I need to copy style of first row and paste it 100 times.
Here is my code

```
$cstart = 2;
$rstart = 49;
$count = 1;
$input = $worksheet->getStyle(num2char($cstart) . $rstart);

foreach ($b_data['rawData'] as $value) {
    $worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($cstart, $rstart, $count++)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($cstart + 1, $rstart, $value['key'])
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($cstart + 5, $rstart, $value['value']);
    $interval = num2char($cstart) . $rstart . ':' . num2char($cstart+5) . $rstart;
    $worksheet->duplicateStyle($input, $interval);

    $rstart++;
}

function num2char($num) {
    $numeric = $num % 26;
    $letter = chr(65 + $numeric);
    $num2 = intval($num / 26);
    if ($num2 > 0) {
        return num2char($num2 - 1) . $letter;
    } else {
        return $letter;
    }
}
```

However, I had the following:

[image]

but what I expected is:

[image]

Is it bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workaround for copying style with PHPExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258318/workaround-for-copying-style-with-phpexcel)

Comment: Check the solution given there, it should help. But I actually don't understand two things in your code: first, why apply `duplicateStyle` for each row (you can do it for the whole range, 'C49:E59', for example), and second, shouldn't it be `num2char($cstart + 5)` instead.

Comment: 1-At first, I tried to apply whole range but it didn't work either. So I tried row by row.  2- Sorry, I changed code so much. Now editing. Thanks.

Comment: The row-by-row approach doesn't work because of the same reasons: `duplicateStyle` is flawed when working with the style supervisor.

Comment: Thanks, using `getXfIndex/setXfIndex` works like charm. How about merged cells? It doesn't merge cells. Doesn't it count as "style"?

Comment: A merged cell is structural, not style, so copying a style will not automatically merge cells, the same as it won't in MS Excel

Answer (score 1):

As Mark pointed out in the comments; a merged cell is structural, not style. So copying the style will not automatically copy the merged cells.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/180) to be able to duplicate entire rows including merged cells

---

One way to deal with this is to check if the cells are part of a merge using the `isInMergeRange()` function like this:

```
$workbook = new PHPExcel;              // prepare the workbook 
$sheet = $workbook->getActiveSheet();   // get the sheet
$sheet->mergeCells('A1:E1');           // merge some cells for tesing
$cell = $sheet->getCell('A1');      // get a cell to check if it is merged
$cell->isInMergeRange()            // check if cell is merged
```

^This returns a Boolean value indicating if it is part of a merged cell.

---

Another function that may interest you is the `isMergeRangeValueCell()` function:

```
$cell->isMergeRangeValueCell()
```

^This returns a Boolean value indicating it is part of a merged cell ***and*** the cell contains the value for the merged range; it returns false in all other situations.