# Copy Cut and Paste the set of rows from one place to other in a excel sheet using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to cut and copy a range of rows  from my excel sheet (about 2346 rows) and paste it in down at the bottom of the sheet. I would like to cut and copy 6-80 rows,331-354 rows and then paste them in bottom,
I would like to know a good way to perform this operation using PHPexcel methods.
Please give me suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Just the data? Or do you need any styling as well?

Comment: if style is not possible to get it's fine i can set it later in the code but atleast if can the data, that will helps a lot

Comment: A combination of `rangeToArray()` and `fromArray()` should allow you to easily copy/paste the data you need; then `removeRow()` to remove the old rows that you copied from

Comment: i have 5 columns as well so what agrument will work in it ?
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A6:E6');  is this right ??do i need to apply a loop to get it from rows 6-80 or is there ant method to do it in other way ?

Comment: $excel_out [] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A6:D6'); 
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($excel_out, "" , 'A2346');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(6);

Comment: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A6:E80');`

Comment: But you should be able to simplify the whole copy/paste block as `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A6:E80'), null, 'A2346');`

Comment: And `removeRow()` accepts a second argument specifying the number of rows to remove: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(6, 80-6+1);`

Comment: thank you for such a perfect answers, but for some reason it gives me this error : Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::range‌​ToArray() excel_ap_export.php on line 101

Comment: i used this in my file : use \PHPExcel_Worksheet; but still it's giving that fatal error i stated above. what could be the possible mistake i am doing here i am not sure

Comment: I'm not certain, unless there's a case-sensitivity error somewhere: you can double-check the `rangeToArray()` method in the source code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64648/discussion-between-maggi-and-mark-baker).

Answer (score 4):

Okay I had nearly the same problem (I just wanted to copy & paste values and styling, without cutting anything).  The solution doesn't seem to quite be solved here, or anywhere that I could find, sooo this is what I did:

```
//Copy & paste values of range of cells
$cellValues = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('C25:AN26');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cellValues, null, 'C89');
```

(I got the same `Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::range‌​ToArray()` error as Maggi above, using Mark's given code, but for some reason breaking it up into 2 lines works);

and then this silly bit of code to copy & paste the styling of the same range:

```
$i = 2;
while ($i < 55) {
    $j = num2char($i);
    $k = num2char($i+1);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($j.'26:'.$k.'26'), $j.'90:'.$k.'90');
    $i++;
}

function num2char($num) {
    $numeric = $num % 26;
    $letter = chr(65 + $numeric);
    $num2 = intval($num / 26);
    if ($num2 > 0) {
        return num2char($num2 - 1) . $letter;
    } else {
        return $letter;
    }
}
```

(num2char function taken directly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800157/php-excel-copy-and-paste-styles-from-one-row-to-other))

And then if you need to cut the original cells, use the `removeRow()` function.

Comment: Your num2char function could be simplified to just `'A' + $num` provided it doesn't go past 'Z'

Comment: This whole problem could be simplified to serving a static Excel file, as long as the data in the file never needs to change. HTH. ;)

Comment: Useful read: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/