# PHPExcel Can't copy Style object

Tags: phpexcel

I want to copy cells styles to an array and than use

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1');
$arr[] = $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1');
$arr[] = $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C1');

//do smth .... 

$PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($arr[0],'A2');
$PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($arr[1],'B2');
$PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($arr[2],'C2');
```

But all cells A2,B2,C2 get the same style as C1.
What's wrong?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Can you check this post - maybe same problem, i think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258318/workaround-for-copying-style-with-phpexcel

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**: Please use the latest version of PHPExcel from [github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

**Solution 2**:
Manually apply fix to the *duplicateStyle()* method in *Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php*
from:

```
if ($this->_parent->cellXfExists($pCellStyle)) {
    // there is already this cell Xf in our collection
    $xfIndex = $pCellStyle->getIndex();
} else {
    // we don't have such a cell Xf, need to add
    $workbook->addCellXf($pCellStyle);
    $xfIndex = $pCellStyle->getIndex();
}
```

change to:

```
if ($existingStyle = $this->_parent->getCellXfByHashCode($pCellStyle-
>getHashCode())) {
    // there is already such cell Xf in our collection
    $xfIndex = $existingStyle->getIndex();
} else {
    // we don't have such a cell Xf, need to add
    $workbook->addCellXf($pCellStyle);
    $xfIndex = $pCellStyle->getIndex();
}
```